# clip and/or intersect tools giving me the wrong results in qgis 2.18.16

Tags: qgis, clip

I have my own digitilized **polygon** (called clipRahmen, north Asia), I wanted to clip all vector layers (points, polygons, lines) within this **polygon** which is an area north Asia, I used "clip" and "intersect", even the tool from the processing toolbox (under Geoalgorithms, Vector, Polygons) "Polygon intersection", but they are giving me the same result, which was the result NOT within this **polygon** that I have created. Data that I'm using is downloaded from Natural Earth, corner coordinate is user-defined: 100 000, layer coordinates WGS84.

In Screenshot u can see that the yellow points (populated places, 10 Mio. -Natural Earth data) are clipped/intersected, violet points are original-not clipped, but are not within the **Polygon**, blue rectangle is my **polygon** (north Asia). Is there any way to get correct clip result without updating the qgis?

**I used the same tool (clip) for same data (points, lines, and polygons) in the same version of QGIS (2.18.16) for another area- was working (clipping and clipped layers were WGS84, corner coordinate was 100 000: user-defined), now is the same, I've just clipped to different area (north Asia), but is not working.**

[image] 
**result:**
[image]

---

Comment: Make sure all layers use the same Coordinate Reference System (CRS).

Comment: The clipping and clipped layers _must_ have the same CRS, otherwise the tools you are using won't give you the expected result.

Comment: @ArMoraer and Chrisnizz  Thanks for your replying! All my layers (clipping and clipped layers) are in same coordinates system(WGS84), but my corner coordinate (right side below in 100 000), I've changed corner coordinate to WGS 84, but I have to digitize my polygon again, coz the shape of my polygon is changed.

Comment: If your polygon has incorrect topology, you may have difficulty overlaying it with valid polygons.

Comment: @Vince How I'll make sure that polygon has correct topology? thank you!

Comment: Topology Checker plugin